# Should oil, spirit or water based stains be used on Medium-density fibreboard (MDF)?

Tags: staining

I've made a recording desk out of 18mm MDF. 
What type of stain and varnish would you recommend and would it need a sealer coat applying first.

All advice appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I really like using a sealing primer like Bin's  Bulls Eye. this is a pigmated shellac based primer that can be sanded smooth as glass. It cures very hard, blocks any stains well and is an excellent base for topcoats. For a top coat, you can use a couple of coats of good grade latex gloss or semi gloss (personal preference).  If you want a really hard protective finish, let the latex paint cure for a couple of days and overcoat it with several coats of WATER  based urethane.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Shirlock. I've done a little research in forums, which suggest MDF dosen't like spirit or water based stains, which leaves the oil based stain. The spirit stain i tried came out looking very patchy, not flattering at all for the desk i've made. So i'll check out the oil based stain next. Thanks again Shirlock.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, my bad, I didn't realize you wanted to do a wood satin.  MDF is a very hard composite made of wood fibers and resin, not wood veneer.  It will not stain well, ever!  It is made to be painted, not stained.

Comment: Ok Shirlock I hear you, and thanks again. Looks like paint it is.